# Why this SVG not working in the EPUB file

Tags: svg, pandoc, epub

I have the bellow pandoc generated xhtml in my EBUP file:

```
cat EPUB/text/ch001.xhtml
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops" xml:lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="generator" content="pandoc" />
  <title>ch001.xhtml</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/stylesheet1.css" />
</head>
<body epub:type="bodymatter">
<section id="valami" class="level1 unnumbered">
<h1 class="unnumbered">valami</h1>
<html>
<body>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<circle r="50"> </circle>
</svg>
<svg class="svg-preview" height="13" id="m_s2tex_0" style="--latex_align: -0.31706pt; --latex_height: 13px; vertical-align:-0.31706pt; opacity: 1" viewbox="1872.019782 1482.72797 4.782067 7.770859" width="8" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs> <path d="m3.207272-6.981816c0-.261818 0-.283636-.250909-.283636c-.676363 .698182-1.636363 .698182-1.985454 .698182v.338182c.218182 0 .861818 0 1.429091-.283636v5.650908c0 .392727-.032727 .523636-1.014545 .523636h-.349091v.338182c.381818-.032727 1.330909-.032727 1.767272-.032727s1.385454 0 1.767272 .032727v-.338182h-.349091c-.981818 0-1.014545-.12-1.014545-.523636v-6.119998z" id="s7g0-49"> </path> </defs> <g id="s7page1"> <!--start 1872.019782 1490.246126 --> <use x="1872.019782" xlink:href="#s7g0-49" y="1490.246126"> </use> </g>
<script type="text/ecmascript">
    if(window.parent.postMessage)window.parent.postMessage("0.31706|6|9.75|"+window.location,"*");
   </script>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

It is basically 2 simple SVG object. The first one is a hand written just for the test and it is working:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<circle r="50"> </circle>
</svg>
```

The second is automatically generated and it is not working.

```
<svg class="svg-preview" height="13" id="m_s2tex_0" style="--latex_align: -0.31706pt; --latex_height: 13px; vertical-align:-0.31706pt; opacity: 1" viewbox="1872.019782 1482.72797 4.782067 7.770859" width="8" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs> <path d="m3.207272-6.981816c0-.261818 0-.283636-.250909-.283636c-.676363 .698182-1.636363 .698182-1.985454 .698182v.338182c.218182 0 .861818 0 1.429091-.283636v5.650908c0 .392727-.032727 .523636-1.014545 .523636h-.349091v.338182c.381818-.032727 1.330909-.032727 1.767272-.032727s1.385454 0 1.767272 .032727v-.338182h-.349091c-.981818 0-1.014545-.12-1.014545-.523636v-6.119998z" id="s7g0-49"> </path> </defs> <g id="s7page1"> <!--start 1872.019782 1490.246126 --> <use x="1872.019782" xlink:href="#s7g0-49" y="1490.246126"> </use> </g>
<script type="text/ecmascript">
    if(window.parent.postMessage)window.parent.postMessage("0.31706|6|9.75|"+window.location,"*");
   </script>
</svg>
```

I have tried to simplified down the second one to see why is not working, but without luck. Anybody have an idea what could be the reason?

**update1:** The file can be opened in Safari and it is rendering both SVG image correctly. I have uploaded a screenshot [here](https://sajozsattilahome.files.wordpress.com/2021/06/kepernyofoto-2021-06-03-9.34.32.png). The first SVG is the quarter circle, the second one is the number 1.

Comment: You were right, the all issue was regarding the full lower case of the viewbox. When it was set to viewBox the problem solved. 
A little background: the HTML code one point of the processing going across a BeautifulSoup parsing, to make it valid XHTML. There the default lxml parser turns everything lowercase, this was cause the issue.
@RobertLongson If you make you comment an answer. I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've written the viewBox attribute as viewbox.

SVG and XHTML are case sensitive languages whereas HTML is not so if the EPUB importer is expecting XHTML then this will be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Most epub viewers that I'm familiar with use a web engine for rendering. So to get your SVG to be visible in an epub, it probably needs to be visible in a web browser.

Trying your second SVG, I don't see anything in Chrome or Firefox. Or in a generic image viewer.

If I add a `stroke=` value to your path, I see "something" in the browser, but it's a tiny little thing. As if the `viewbox` and/or the `use` settings are confusing the browser.

Comment: For me the I can see the SVG from browser, I have tested in Safari and Firefox. Firefox actually do not render the first one, which is working on EPUB, but render the second. I have uploaded an image about it: https://sajozsattilahome.files.wordpress.com/2021/06/kepernyofoto-2021-06-03-9.34.32.png.  The second SVG image is a number 1.

Comment: But you look, right in the point, the problem is looks like connected to the viewbox and use.

Comment: Wow. I thought browser support for SVG was more consistent. I was testing in Chrome and Firefox on Linux; Mac Webkit apparently has a different behavior set.